# Caffe network getting very low loss but very bad accuracy in testing

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I'm somewhat new to caffe, and I'm getting some strange behavior.  I'm trying to use fine tuning on the bvlc_reference_caffenet to accomplish an OCR task.

I've taken their pretrained net, changed the last FC layer to the number of output classes that I have, and retrained.  After a few thousand iterations I'm getting loss rates of ~.001, and an accuracy over 90 percent when the network tests.  That said, when I try to run my network on data by myself, I get awful results, not exceeding 7 or 8 percent.

The code I'm using to run the net is:

```
[imports]

net = caffe.Classifier('bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt', 'bvlc_reference_caffenet/caffenet_train_iter_28000.caffemodel',  
                       image_dims=(227, 227, 1))

input_image = caffe.io.load_image('/Training_Processed/6/0.png')    
prediction = net.predict([input_image])  # predict takes any number of images, and formats them for the Caffe net automatically    
cls = prediction[0].argmax()
```

Any thoughts on why this performance might be so poor?

Thanks!

PS: Some additional information which may or not be of use.  When classifying as shown below, the classifier really seems to favor certain classes.  Even though I have a 101 class problem, it seems to only assign a max of 15 different classes

PPS: I'm also fairly certain I'm not overfitting.  I've been testing this along the way with snapshots and they all exhibit the same poor results.

Answer (score 5):

Your code for testing the model you posted seem to miss some components:

1. It seems like you did not subtract the image's mean.
2. You did not swap channels from RGB to BGR.
3. You did not scale the inputs to [0..255] range.

Looking at similar instances of `caffe.Classifier` you may see something like:

```
net = caffe.Classifier('bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt',
                       'bvlc_reference_caffenet/caffenet_train_iter_28000.caffemodel', 
                       mean = NP.load( 'ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy' ),
                       input_scale=1.0, raw_scale=255,
                       channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                       image_dims=(227, 227, 1))
```

It is **crucial** to have the same input transformation in test as in training.