# Caffe model gives same output for every image

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I just loaded alexnet in caffe using predefined prototxt and caffemodel files. However sending any image to the model returns the same value as output of fc7 layer.

Here is the code snippet

```
net=caffe.Net('alexnet/train_val.prototxt','alexnet/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel',caffe.TEST) 

for image in images:
    im = np.array(caffe.io.load_image(image))
    im = caffe.io.resize_image(im, (227, 227))
    im = np.array(im,dtype=np.float32)
    im =255*im;
    im = im[:,:,::-1]
    im -= np.array(((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434)))
    im = im.transpose(2,0,1)
    net.blobs['data'].reshape(1,*im.shape)
    net.blobs['data'].data[...] = im
    net.forward()
    fc = net.blobs['fc7'].data #Always the same value
```

Comment: shouldnt it be fc8,the one in loss layer? https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_alexnet/train_val.prototxt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caffe network getting very low loss but very bad accuracy in testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434671/caffe-network-getting-very-low-loss-but-very-bad-accuracy-in-testing)

Comment: you do not transform the input image as it was transformed during training. Especially, you are not subtracting the mean.

Comment: @Shai I have made the necessary changes to make the preprocessing same as that in training

Comment: @Harjatin check the range of your values. I think you need to multiply by 255

Comment: why don't you use caffe.io.resize to resize the image?

Comment: @Shai I made both the changes

Comment: why are you using `train_val.prototxt` and not `deploy.prototxt`?

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?